# How to detect mouse click outside listview items?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a ListView with a few Items, so whenever I selected a specific item, a corresponding event will occur. Besides, I also want to create some events when user click to empty space within the ListView (where there is no items). However, I have tried to create MouseClick and SelectionChanged for the ListView, it still cannot detect mouse click outside items.

Comment: WPF or Forms? Use the tags.

Comment: Why do you need to detect mouse clicks outside the items? You've said above that you want an event to fire when you click a ListViewItem, right?

Comment: @furkle, cause i want when user click outside the listview, i reset some flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a little outside the scope of your design, but this is the kind of thing that'd be a pretty easy to do in an MVVM design. Rather than having to worry about whether the user clicked on an item, or on any of the other non-item space within the ListView, you can just OneWayToSource or TwoWay bind a property to the ListView's SelectedItem. Then, whenever that value is set, you can execute whatever code you want in the property's setter field.

In your XAML:

```
<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem Mode=OneWayToSource}"></ListView>
```

And then in the ViewModel serving as DataContext for your ListView:

```
private object yourSelectedItem = new object();
public object YourSelectedItem
{
    get { return yourSelectedItem; }
    set
    {
         yourSelectedItem = value;
         CorrespondingEvent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the MouseDown event - it'll work for outside space